# Can't open popup using JQuery and magnific popup.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I've loaded magnific popup.js library to display a popup for a form.

HTML:

```
    <a class="popup-with-form" href="#test-form">Open form</a>

<form id="test-form" class="mfp-hide white-popup-block">
        <h1>Form</h1>

    <fieldset style="border:0;">
        <p>Lightbox has an option to automatically focus on the first input. It's strongly recommended to use <code>inline</code> popup type for lightboxes with form instead of <code>ajax</code> (to keep entered data if the user accidentally refreshed the page).</p>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required="">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" required="">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Eg. +447500000000" required="">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="textarea">Textarea</label>
                <br>
                <textarea id="textarea">Try to resize me to see how popup CSS-based resizing works.</textarea>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.popup-with-form').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        preloader: false,
        focus: '#name',

        // When elemened is focused, some mobile browsers in some cases zoom in
        // It looks not nice, so we disable it:
        callbacks: {
            beforeOpen: function () {
                if ($(window).width() < 700) {
                    this.st.focus = false;
                } else {
                    this.st.focus = '#name';
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This isn't displaying the form in a popup as expected. You may see the example with dependencies  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nuno/yWpC4/2/)

Comment: The popup opened for me in FF and the form is displayed. It needs to be cleaned up some, but other than that it works. Have you looked at the console in the browser that you're testing in for errors?

Comment: I get no errors/messages in the console. The popup in Chrome is just a blank screen wiht the input fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magnific popup doesn't apply any styles to the popup.  You have to do it yourself: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#inline_type.  If you want to make it look like their example add:

```
.white-popup-block {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yWpC4/3/